Type of Vue reference in a component with a generic type
I am using Vue 3 (Composition API) with Typescript. Here is my code.
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T">
import { ref, Ref } from "vue";

const props = defineProps<{
  myProp: T;
}>();

const model: Ref<T> = ref(props.myProp);
</script>

My IDE (WebStorm 2024.1.2 with Vue Language Server 1.8.27) tells me:
"Vue: Type Ref<UnwrapRef<T>> is not assignable to type Ref<T>",
"Type UnwrapRef<T> is not assignable to type T"
Final Edit: This line was indeed producing an error on build.
I resolved this by using shallowRef (in my case, T has no nested fields anyway):
const model: ShallowRef<T> = shallowRef(props.getValue);

Another possibility, suggested in this issue, is to cast our ref as follows:
const model = ref<T>(props.getValue) as Ref<T>;

But this does not seem appropriate, because if type T has some nested refs, the type of model.value (that is UnwrapRef<T>) will not indeed be assignable to the type T.
Moreover, ESLint still complains about the above piece of code:
"ESLint: This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.(@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion)"

The type need to be specified as either model: Ref<T> or as Ref<T>, not both, that's what linter warning is about. A preferable way to use generics is to specify them for for functions that support generic params, ref<T>(props.myProp), it needs to be tested if this will result in correct type due to how Vue reactive types are transformed. You can tag a question with IDE-related tags, currently the problem is specific to IDE, also Jetbrains team is active on SO

@EstusFlask Thanks for your comment! Indeed, I tried the as Ref<T> just to make sure that my linter was correctly inferring the type. Now if I use ref<T>(props.myProp), the linter stops complaining about the declaration of model, but then whenever I try to assign the value to some object of type T it complains that "Type T is not assignable to type UnwrapRef<T>" (which is another issue). Yet I cannot understand why const model: Ref<T> = ref(props.myProp); is not working...

This may be specific to "script setup" which is a proprietary blackbox already, and now there's another level of uncertainty with "generic". But : vs as is type compatibility. You can produce the correct type with ref<T>(), and you can type wrong ref() type with as Ref<T> but not assign wrong type to model: Ref<T>. Roughly the same as let a: string = 'foo'; let b: 'foo' = a as 'foo', wouldn't work without as.

In your case the error means that the structure of model.value may differ from an object it's assigned to (T type) due to ref unwrapping, you need to guarantee it's the same, i.e. prop object doesn't contain nested refs that could be unwrapped. This is where type assertion is necessary
